# Permission denied (publickey). On Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-keys

I am new to SSH and have been looking for a solution for this for long now.
I am trying to connect to my uni's server that runs on Ubuntu from my WSL (I am using wsl2) via ssh. My Subsystem also runs on Ubuntu (20.04.4).

My supervisor manually added my public key to my user account. He also tested to connect to my user with his key, which worked.

However, whenever I am trying to connect, I simply get the error message

```
user@hostname: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I also tried connecting with the same key to a testing server, which worked perfectly fine. So the flaw can't be with my key.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

PS:

For anyone that has the patience to read through the connection log:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/luca/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/luca/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for cog_mod
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "hostname" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to hostname [134.2.42.97] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to hostname:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from hostname
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Uh2TNabn6QmSPX7qC0to6eZ1fH08Y7SKDObpoh4OTQg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from hostname
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 134.2.42.97
debug1: Host 'hostname' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/luca/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa RSA SHA256:zDHcVHXmiDIIqxa0JAwXzgqjaG9izz6fCLhMGuPDsQw explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa RSA SHA256:zDHcVHXmiDIIqxa0JAwXzgqjaG9izz6fCLhMGuPDsQw explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@hostname: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Connection log to test server is identical up to the fifth to last line, from there it differentiates as

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa RSA SHA256:zDHcVHXmiDIIqxa0JAwXzgqjaG9izz6fCLhMGuPDsQw explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa RSA SHA256:zDHcVHXmiDIIqxa0JAwXzgqjaG9izz6fCLhMGuPDsQw explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:zDHcVHXmiDIIqxa0JAwXzgqjaG9izz6fCLhMGuPDsQw
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:zDHcVHXmiDIIqxa0JAwXzgqjaG9izz6fCLhMGuPDsQw
Enter passphrase for key '/home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa':
```

My ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host cog_mod
    Hostname hostname
    User user
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile /home/luca/.ssh/BT_id_rsa
```

Comment: My first assumption would be, since you've confirmed that your key works on another server, that your supervisor added it incorrectly.  Do you have any way of confirming the validity of the public key on the uni server?  You can also add `ssh -vvv` to get some more detailed logging/debugging/info.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I told my supervisor about my issues. To his knowledge, everything from the server side should be fine. Thanks for the tip with ssh -vvv! I attached the connection log above. Comparing to the log of my test server, the protocol seems to fail at the fourth to last line `debug3: receive packet: type 51`

Comment: Can you provide the logs from the server when the successful attempt was made?

Comment: @Ramhound also added that above.

Comment: @luCAT `Type 51`, in my understanding, is almost always server-side, and typically permission related.  Have your supervisor check `/var/log/auth.log` on the server-side.  I'd also ask for the results of your server-side `stat ~/.ssh` (700) and `stat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (600).  They both should be owned by you (I wonder if your supervisor owns `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).  The thing that doesn't quite make sense is that your supervisor says he was able to log in as you using his key ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds also doesn't quite make sense to me. I also googled a bit and `Type 51` indeed usually seems to be on the sever-side. I will check in with my supervisor again. That might take a few days though. Thanks again!

Comment: Ask him to double check the username of the user created for you on the server, and the filename / location of `authorized_keys`.